# Cannot upload file via django form running apache/linux

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I could use some help deciphering the following traceback and resolving specifically on a linux machine running apache and django with `DEBUG = False`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 256, in handle_uncaught_exception
    'request': request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1200, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1293, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1303, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1343, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 766, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
    self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
    mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
    mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
...
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It is unclear to me why `send_mail(..., fail_silently=True, ...)` should fail if `fail_silently=True`

How do I debug this error if it only manifests when `DEBUG = False?`

Comment: it looks like your mail server is unreachable. Did you set up your email settings properly?

Comment: Yes. I am able to mail out password reset links, etc. Besides, what is `fail_silently=False` supposed to do if the mail server is not set up properly/correctly?